# Python TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects in my email body part of message

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to send some data in my email code in the body part of the email message.  I am calling a function which returns a string and I am calling another function which returns a list.  I would like to include these into the email body part of the message.
I am getting the error TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/test_runners 2 edit project in progress add more tests/selenium_regression_test_5_1_1/Email/email_selenium_report.py", line 32, in <module>
    report.send_report_summary_from_htmltestrunner_selenium_report2()
  File "E:\test_runners 2 edit project in progress add more tests\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\Email\report.py", line 520, in send_report_summary_from_htmltestrunner_selenium_report2
    extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner()) + "\n Report location = : \\storage-1\Testing\Selenium_Test_Report_Results\ClearCore_5_1_1\Selenium VM\IE11 \n")
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects
```

The line in my email code where the message body part is:

```
msg = MIMEText("\n ClearCore 5_1_1 Automated GUI Test_IE11_Selenium_VM   \n " + extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner() + "\n extract_header_count__from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner() \n" + list(
      extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner()) + "\n Report location = : \\storage-1\Testing\Selenium_Test_Report_Results\ClearCore_5_1_1\Selenium VM\IE11 \n")
```

My email code is:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
def send_report_summary_from_htmltestrunner_selenium_report2():
    print extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()
    print extract_header_count__from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()
    all_testcases = list(extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner())
    # print all_data
    pprint.pprint(all_testcases)
    msg = MIMEText("\n ClearCore 5_1_1 Automated GUI Test_IE11_Selenium_VM   \n " + extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner() + "\n extract_header_count__from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner() \n" + list(
          extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner()) + "\n Report location = : \\storage-1\Testing\Selenium_Test_Report_Results\ClearCore_5_1_1\Selenium VM\IE11 \n")

    msg['Subject'] = "ClearCore 5_1_1 Automated GUI Test"
    msg['to'] = "riaz.ladhani@company.onmicrosoft.com"
    msg['From'] = "system@company.com"

    s = smtplib.SMTP()
    s.connect(host=SMTP_SERVER)
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
    s.close()
```

The function which returns the list is:

```
def extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner():
    filename = (r"E:\test_runners 2 edit project\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\ClearCore501_Automated_GUI_TestReport.html")
    html_report_part = open(filename,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part, "html.parser")
    for div in soup.select("#result_table tr div.testcase"):
          yield div.text.strip().encode('utf-8'), div.find_next("a").text.strip().encode('utf-8')
```

The other 2 functions which I am calling which returns a string are:

```
def extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner():
    filename = (r"E:\test_runners 2 edit project\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\ClearCore501_Automated_GUI_TestReport.html")
    html_report_part = open(filename,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part, "html.parser")
    table = soup.select_one("#result_table")

    #Create list here...
    results = []

    headers = [td.text for td in table.select_one("#header_row").find_all("td")[1:-1]]
#    print(" ".join(headers))

    #Don't forget to append header (if you want)
    results.append(headers)
    return results


def extract_header_count__from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner():
    filename = (r"E:\test_runners 2 edit project\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\ClearCore501_Automated_GUI_TestReport.html")
    html_report_part = open(filename,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part, "html.parser")
    table = soup.select_one("#result_table")

    #Create list here...
    results = []
    for row in table.select("tr.passClass"):
        #Store row string in variable and append before printing
        row_str = " ".join([td.text for td in row.find_all("td")[1:-1]])
        results.append(row_str)
#        print(row_str)

    return results
```

How can I include the data from these functions into the body part of the email message?
I tried to concatenate it but that did not work because it says you cannot concatenate string and a list.

Thanks, Riaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
msg = MIMEText("\n ClearCore 5_1_1 Automated GUI Test_IE11_Selenium_VM   \n " + extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner() + "\n extract_header_count__from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner() \n" + list(
      extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner()) + "\n Report location = : \\storage-1\Testing\Selenium_Test_Report_Results\ClearCore_5_1_1\Selenium VM\IE11 \n")
```

You are explicitly trying to concat a list and strings which is impossible.

**EDIT** *ALL* of your functions return a list instead of strings.

If your expected outcome is a string you can use `'\n'.join` to turn the list to a string with `'\n'` between every element in the list:

```
msg = MIMEText("\n ClearCore 5_1_1 Automated GUI Test_IE11_Selenium_VM   \n " + 
               '\n'.join(extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()) +
               '\n'.join(extract_header_count__from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()) +   
               '\n'.join(extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner()) + 
               "\n Report location = : \\storage-1\Testing\Selenium_Test_Report_Results\ClearCore_5_1_1\Selenium VM\IE11 \n")
```

I might have lost some `'\n'` when formatting, you should add them back if you require them.

It will also be a bit more readable if you change the return values of the function to strings instead of converting inside the call to `MIMEText`, for example

```
def extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner():
    filename = (r"E:\test_runners 2 edit project\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\ClearCore501_Automated_GUI_TestReport.html")
    html_report_part = open(filename,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part, "html.parser")
    table = soup.select_one("#result_table")

    results = []

    headers = [td.text for td in table.select_one("#header_row").find_all("td")[1:-1]]

    results.append(headers)

    # Use whatever character you want as a "separator" instead of '\n'
    return '\n'.join(results)
```

Comment: I tried your function extract_only_header_from_summary_report_htmltestrunner.  I get the error TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found

Comment: The line highlighted with the error is on return '\n'.join(results)

Comment: @RiazLadhani Oh. I missed the fact that `results` is a list of lists, though it seems that there is no need for it to be. You can remove the `results` variable, then `return '\n'.join(headers)`.

Comment: I've got further now.  I get the error TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found in send_report_summary_from_htmltestrunner_selenium_report2
    '\n'.join(extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner())

Comment: I am not sure how I can covert my functions to return strings instead of list.  I did do a string variable first but when i called my function it only returned the first value from the for loop.  I changed it to return string and then I got all the values out from the for loop

Comment: @RiazLadhani You're returning an iterator of `(str, str)` instead of just `str`. So you have to chain the output before `'\n'.join`. Check my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  I got it working now.

Answer (score -2):

An illustration of the problem you have:

```
In [2]: lst_of_str = ['abc', 'def']

In [3]: s = 'g'

In [4]: s + lst_of_str
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-45caf5564ff0> in <module>()
----> 1 s + lst_of_str

TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

In [5]: s + ''.join(lst_of_str)
Out[5]: 'gabcdef'
```

The point is, you have to convert your list explicitly to a string. Note that you wouldn't want the result by calling `str` on the list:

```
In [6]: s + str(lst_of_str)
Out[6]: "g['abc', 'def']"
```

**EDIT**

Also note in your function you have

```
yield div.text.strip().encode('utf-8'), div.find_next("a").text.strip().encode('utf-8')
```

it returns a tuple of `(str, str)` instead of a str. If you want to include both of them in your email body, you need to "make them flat". For example,

```
import itertools
s + '\n'.join(itertools.chain(extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner()))
```

Comment: I doubt OP wants `"['abc', 'def']"` as output. Better use `join` for that: `', '.join(['abc', 'def'])` `>> 'abc, def'`.

Comment: @DeepSpace By `str(list)` I was trying to point out that he wouldn't want to do it that way.