# Python TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found in message body of email code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to send some data in my email code in the body part of the email message. I am calling 2 functions which returns a list. I would like to include these into the email body part of the message. I am getting the error TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/test_runners 2 edit project in progress add more tests/selenium_regression_test_5_1_1/Email/email_selenium_report.py", line 32, in <module>
    report.send_report_summary_from_htmltestrunner_selenium_report2()
  File "E:\test_runners 2 edit project in progress add more tests\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\Email\report.py", line 318, in send_report_summary_from_htmltestrunner_selenium_report2
    '\n'.join(extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner()) +
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found
```

My email code is:

```
def send_report_summary_from_htmltestrunner_selenium_report2():
    print extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()
    print extract_header_count__from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()
    all_testcases = list(extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner())
    # print all_data
    pprint.pprint(all_testcases)

    msg = MIMEText("\n ClearCore 5_1_1 Automated GUI Test_IE11_Selenium_VM   \n " +
                   '\n'.join(extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()) +
                   '\n'.join(extract_header_count__from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()) +
                   '\n'.join(extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner()) +
                   "\n Report location = : \\storage-1\Testing\Selenium_Test_Report_Results\ClearCore_5_1_1\Selenium VM\IE11 \n")


    msg['Subject'] = "ClearCore 5_1_1 Automated GUI Test"
    msg['to'] = "riaz.ladhani@company.onmicrosoft.com"
    msg['From'] = "system@company.com"

    s = smtplib.SMTP()
    s.connect(host=SMTP_SERVER)
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
    s.close()
```

My 3 functions which return the list are:

```
def extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner():
    filename = (r"E:\test_runners 2 edit project\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\ClearCore501_Automated_GUI_TestReport.html")
    html_report_part = open(filename,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part, "html.parser")
    table = soup.select_one("#result_table")

    #Create list here...
    results = []

    headers = [td.text for td in table.select_one("#header_row").find_all("td")[1:-1]]
#    print(" ".join(headers))

    #Don't forget to append header (if you want)
    results.append(headers)
    return results


def extract_header_count__from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner():
    filename = (r"E:\test_runners 2 edit project\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\ClearCore501_Automated_GUI_TestReport.html")
    html_report_part = open(filename,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part, "html.parser")
    table = soup.select_one("#result_table")

    #Create list here...
    results = []
    for row in table.select("tr.passClass"):
        #Store row string in variable and append before printing
        row_str = " ".join([td.text for td in row.find_all("td")[1:-1]])
        results.append(row_str)
#        print(row_str)

    return results

def extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner():
    filename = (r"E:\test_runners 2 edit project\selenium_regression_test_5_1_1\TestReport\ClearCore501_Automated_GUI_TestReport.html")
    html_report_part = open(filename,'r')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_report_part, "html.parser")
    for div in soup.select("#result_table tr div.testcase"):
          yield div.text.strip().encode('utf-8'), div.find_next("a").text.strip().encode('utf-8')
```

How can I include the return values from the functions into the email body?

Comment: `extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner()` looks to me to be a generator that produces *tuples*, not lists. Are you sure your exception is generated by the code you posted here? Also, why use `all_testcases = list(extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner())` then call the same method again and ignore that list you already produced? Either way, you'd need to flatten out the sequence, you are trying to join those tuples `str.join([(str1, str2), (str3, str4), ...]) where you (probably?) want to join the contained strings.

Comment: all_testcases = list(extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner())  I did a print on this to see if i get the values i was expecting.  I then know my function was working ok.

Comment: `extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()` does return a list of lists. Again, you can't just join those lists; you'd need to flatten them out.

Comment: I would I flatten them out, I don't know how to do that? Thanks,

Comment: Use [itertools](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38953122/671072). Answered your question there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()` and `extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner()` produce sequences of sequences (the first a list of lists, the other a generator yielding tuples). Neither are suitable for `str.join()`, which can only take a sequence of *strings*.

Either join those nested sequences individually, or flatten out the sequences.

You can use a nested list comprehension to join the nested sequences:

```
'\n'.join([' - '.join(seq) for seq in extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()])
```

or just nest the loops to flatten out the nested structures:

```
'\n'.join([elem
           for seq in extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()
           for elem in seq])
```

The latter can also be achieved with the [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
'\n'.join(chain.from_iterable(extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()))
```

The difference is in what you want the result to be; flatten out if `[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]` should all end up on separate lines, using a nested `str.join()` loop if you need to join `'a'` and `'b'` together differently, then join the result with the joined result of `'c'` and `'d'` with a newline in between.

Note that `extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()` appears to create a nested list for just one element:

```
results = []

headers = [td.text for td in table.select_one("#header_row").find_all("td")[1:-1]]
results.append(headers)

return results
```

That's just *one* `results.append()` call; you could just as well return `headers` there and avoid having to unwrap in the first place.

Comment: I have added '\n'.join([' - '.join(seq) for seq in extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()]) +
                   '\n'.join([elem
                              for seq in extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()
                              for elem in seq]) +
                    "\n Report location = : \\storage-1\Testing\Selenium_Test_Report_Results\ClearCore_5_1_1\Selenium VM\IE11 \n")

Comment: In the for elem in seq]) + I get the error    for elem in seq]) +
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found

Comment: @RiazLadhani: so you have more levels of nesting. You can use `str.join()` only on strings.

Comment: I just do msg = MIMEText("\n ClearCore 5_1_1 Automated GUI Test_IE11_Selenium_VM   \n " +
                   '\n'.join(extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()))  I get the error TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found

Comment: Ok so for the strings I need to do str.join()

Comment: @RiazLadhani: `extract_only_header_from_summary_from_report_htmltestrunner()` returns a list with one list in it. Rather pointless really, when you could just return that one list. Added that observation to my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  Got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

Your function extract_testcases_from_report_htmltestrunner returns a tuple, not a single value. So basically, you might end up with something like this:

```
'\n'.join([('a','b'), ('c', 'd')]
```

And this does simply not work in python.